# Изменение размера виджета в зависимости от изменения размера окна приложения

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы размер виджета менялся вместе с размером окна?

В данном случае я пытаюсь изменять размер виджета взяв в качестве размера размеры окна. Но при запуске программы, если я меняю размер окна, размер виджета не меняется.

```
self.verticalWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, Dialog.width(), Dialog.height()))
```

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(900, 900)

        self.verticalWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, Dialog.width(), Dialog.height()))
        self.verticalWidget.setObjectName("verticalWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.Welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.Welcome.setFont(font)
        self.Welcome.setObjectName("Welcome")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Welcome)
        self.Explanation = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Explanation.setFont(font)
        self.Explanation.setObjectName("Explanation")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Explanation)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.verticalWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.Welcome.setText(_translate("Dialog", ""))
        self.Explanation.setText(_translate("Dialog", ""))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте этот виджет в менеджер компоновки, созданный для главного окна.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(900, 900)

        self.verticalWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, Dialog.width(), Dialog.height()))
        self.verticalWidget.setObjectName("verticalWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.Welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.Welcome.setFont(font)
        self.Welcome.setObjectName("Welcome")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Welcome)
        
        self.Explanation = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.Explanation.setFont(font)
        self.Explanation.setObjectName("Explanation")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Explanation)
        
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.verticalWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.Welcome.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Welcome"))
        self.Explanation.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Explanation"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)               # !!! +++
        self.layout.addWidget(self.verticalWidget)              # !!! +++



style = '''
#verticalWidget {
    background-color: #4B8673;
}
#Explanation {
    color: #F6FBF4;
}
'''
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(style)                     # +++   
    
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]